# Comparing offset-naive and -aware datetimes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have a list of dates in an array, I'd like to keep only the ones that has expired in order to erase them later. But I'm trying to pass an IF condition on each dates in the array and print only the ones that has expired. The problem is that I don't understand how I can do it with Python.

Here is what I thought doing :

```
# model.objects.all() contains the dates of each objects

for data in model.objects.all():
    if data.created_date < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=20):
        print(data.created_date)
```

The code above gives me this error :

> TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

What am I doing wrong, what's the solution ?

Comment: Python does not have arrays. What you have there looks like a Django QuerySet. You should filter it with the proper `.filter()` call.

Comment: @KlausD. how is it possible to filter Django queryset by expiration time ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Comment: Please reform your question to include all the information required to solve the actual problem. Add your model, tag as django, explain the task. Your approach does seem to be the best practice way for Django.

Comment: @KlausD. I removed my question since it was out of the scope of this one, the advice you gave me solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now, timedelta

expired_date = now() - timedelta(seconds=20)
```

If you want to see them:

```
model_list = YourModel.objects.filter(created_date__lt=expired_date)

for model_item in model_list:
    print model_item.created_date
```

If you just want to remove them:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(created_date__lt=expired_date).delete()
```